# Laravel + Vite + Docker : build files 404 not found

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, vite

this week I've been struggling with an issue.
I have a laravel/vuejs (using typescript) with vite project.  I am using Laravel 8.74.0
Here is my packages versions :

```
* "vite": "3.0.4",
* "laravel-vite": "^0.0.19", 
* "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.2.2",
* "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
* "vue": "^3.2.6",
```

My issue is that when I try to build my project throught docker, the public/build files are created but the browser return me a 404 not found.

```
GET http://foo.localhost:8000/build/assets/main.80098a01.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://foo.localhost:8000/build/assets/main.b7cb1660.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Notice : the "foo" before localhost is present because I am using Tenancy for Laravel

I verified and the build directory exist in the app container.

I am using docker compose to build the image.
docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - laravel
  
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    expose:
      - 3000:3000

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=fresh_final
    networks:
      - laravel
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: fresh-pma
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 49152:80
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
        - laravel
volumes:
    db:
        driver: local
```

Because I only have one project with both laravel and vuejs, I decided to create one container for the frontend and the backend.

app.dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.21-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    sudo

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install extensions
# RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql exif pcntl bcmath gd
# RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
# RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
# RUN sudo passwd www
# # Install nodejs
RUN sudo curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm install --global yarn
# RUN rm -rf node_modules
# Change current user to www
USER www

# Copy existing application directory contents
# COPY . /var/www/html

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/html


# RUN whoami
RUN yarn install
# RUN sudo chown -R www: /var/www/html/node_modules
# RUN node node_modules/esbuild/install.js


# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
# EXPOSE 3000

# COPY --from=vuejs /app /var/www/html

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

nginx.dockerfile

```
 FROM nginx

ADD docker/conf/vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

vhost.conf

```
upstream app {
  server app:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "laravel-vite";
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    define: {
        'process.env': process.env
    },
    server: {
        host: true,
        port: 3000,
        watch: {
            usePolling: true
        }
          
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/scripts/main.ts'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    // The Vue plugin will re-write asset URLs, when referenced
                    // in Single File Components, to point to the Laravel web
                    // server. Setting this to `null` allows the Laravel plugin
                    // to instead re-write asset URLs to point to the Vite
                    // server instead.
                    base: null,
 
                    // The Vue plugin will parse absolute URLs and treat them
                    // as absolute paths to files on disk. Setting this to
                    // `false` will leave absolute URLs un-touched so they can
                    // reference assets in the public directly as expected.
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/views/src',
        },
    },
});
```

Also, I noticed that the docker image run perfectly fine when I ran the build locally. So I am assuming that the docker image is referencing the local build files. (When the local build directory is deleted, the 404 not found error reappears).

Comment: same issue, follow

Comment: I'm also getting similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it:
Explicitly specify ports 5173:5173 in the docker-compose.yml for the PHP container. As far as I understood, these are the standard ports for NPM

```
laravel_php:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    container_name: laravel_php
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
      - laravel_db
    networks:
      - default
```

And for the vite.config.js file, you need to add the following settings to the server variable

```
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hmr: {
        clientPort: 5173,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    watch: {
        usePolling: true
    }
}
```

If necessary, I could share my Docker setup